# javascript jquery .show() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason .hide works, but .show not?
This is my code:

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="alertShowAccount()">Add account</button>

 <script>

  function alertHideAccount() {
    $("#addAccount").hide();
  }

  function alertShowAccount() {
    $("#addAccount").show();
  }

 </script>

 <div style="display:none" id="addAccount">
    <button class="btn btn-md" onclick="alertHideAccount()">Cancel</button>
 </div>

<body>
```

Anyone has an idea why it is not working? The function IS being called, I tested it with an alert. Also the console gives no errors.

Comment: Place the script tag under the body tag.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy That did not change anything unfortunately

Comment: @MatthewDotcom Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: Works as is for me: https://jsfiddle.net/6g5kqgL7/

Comment: This code does actually work, problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: You're also better off using jQuery for capturing the events rather than inline JS.

Comment: Do you by chance have other elements with the id `addAccount` on the real page?

Comment: @JasonP Nop, this is the only one..

Comment: @JasonP Nevermind, I had a other id 'addAccount' but it loaded from a other page so I didn't noticed. Problem is now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @Andy - Wrapping the functions in a ready handler will *break* them, because then they won't be global and thus won't be accessible from the element onClick attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did man, it worked for me this way...

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#addAccount').hide();

  $('#hide_div').on('click',function(){
    $("#addAccount").hide();
  });

  $('#show_div').on('click',function(){
    $("#addAccount").show();
  });

});
 </script>
<body>

  <button id="show_div">Add account</button>


 <div id="addAccount">
    <button class="btn btn-md" id='hide_div'>Cancel</button>
 </div>

<body>
```

So here's what happened, we changed Onclick to just the ID of the element, and called it on the script with $(elem).on('event',function());